# Double ArrayList multiplication

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have three Double Arraylists. I want to multiple array 1 to array 2 and put it in the third array.

```
// ArrayList 1 
[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]

// ArrayList 2 
// Random number generated by random()
[0.37668669271524147, 0.429455596516655, 0.7337191115424969, 0.29389239043901294, 0.7050413406305202]
```

And My code

```
for (int i = 0; i < plans.size(); i++) {

    for (int j = 0; i < value.size(); j++) {
        try { 
            plansval.add(plans.get(i) * value.get(j)); 
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

I get `IndexOutofBoundsExceptions`. 
Could you please help me to solve this issue thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. Just change

```
 for (int j = 0; i < value.size(); j++) {
```

to

```
 for (int j = 0; j < value.size(); j++) {
```

Comment: Thanks. Such a simple things that I did not see it.